# How to find x number of closest neighbours matching criteria in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix, closest

I have an m*n matrix with values of 0-9. Basically, what I want to do is be able to find all cells that have a 0 as their value and find the k closest neighbours that aren't 0.

My code right now is along the lines of this:

- locate all cells with a zero and make an a*2 matrix holding their x
  and y locations
- do the same for all cells without 0
- make a loop that cycles through each given zero coordinate and
  measure the distance from it to every non-zero cell and record it in
  row one of a new matrix (row 2 and 3 are the x and y coordinates,
  respectively)
- use sortrows() to get this matrix in ascending order and then extract
  the first k values (ie, the closest k number of coordinates)
- repeat

What I was hoping to do was more along the lines of quickly finding the k closest non-zero cells without an internal loop and then repeating for each 0 cell. Any advice would be greatly appreciated, thanks very much.

Comment: do you think `knnsearch` would be any helpful? Btw, be aware that you need the **Statistical Toolbox** to have access to it.

Comment: I did consider it, but not allowed to use the knnsearch function for this particular task. Thanks anyways.

Comment: What about [`dsearchn`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dsearchn.html)? Edit: See my answer below for details.

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this problem by finding all the nonzero entries, e.g. as you are currently doing, and then determining the corresponding vertices. You can then use [`dsearchn`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dsearchn.html) to find the k nearest points. If you want to do this repeatedly, you will benefit from constructing a [`delaunayTriangulation`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/delaunaytriangulationclass.html) object.